# Ajax source from local file, will it decrease page load time?

Tags: ajax, datatables

I'm following this example with DataTables
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

Ajax loads data from a big txt file into the grid.

When visiting a static web page with this data, will the browser download the txt file completely - or only load what is needed?

Thank you!

Comment: "load what is needed" - you mean what you define in your function that handles the returned object from server? You have two ways to filter data - on client and on server side. Check in browser dev tools - "Network/XHR"

Comment: It will download the `.txt` completely

Comment: I monitored the response of above link in network tab. It is downloading complete file at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course that will download the txt file completely and then it will (sort-filter-arrange data into pages etc) data to your datatable.

The ajax call in this case is not very useful indeed but sometimes is a lifesaver.